# MPI_Rsend not raising error when it should

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

The [man page for Open MPI's implementation of MPI_Rsend](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Rsend.3.php) states that

> A ready send may only be called if the user can guarantee that a receive is already posted. It is an error if the receive is not posted before the ready send is called.

I'm trying to write a small program to see how this error would manifest itself (I thought it would be a runtime error followed by abort), but this program works perfectly:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  /* malloc */
#include <unistd.h>  /* sleep */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

  int my_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

  const int ARRAY_SIZE = 100000;

  int* array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * ARRAY_SIZE);
  assert(array != NULL);

  if (my_rank == 0) {
    // Populate array with something.
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) { array[i] = i; }

    int error_val;
    printf("[%d] Called Rsend\n", my_rank);
    error_val = MPI_Rsend(array, ARRAY_SIZE, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("[%d] Done with success? %d\n", my_rank, error_val == MPI_SUCCESS);
  }
  else {
    sleep(5);
    MPI_Recv(array, ARRAY_SIZE, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("[%d] Last element of array is: %d\n", my_rank,
           array[ARRAY_SIZE -1 ]);
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
$ mpicc -o mpi_rsend_example mpi_rsend_example.c
$ mpiexec -n 2 ./mpi_rsend_example
[0] Called Rsend
[0] Done with success? 1
[1] Last element of array is: 99999
```

Shouldn't there be an error, since the `MPI_Recv` call certainly happens *after* the `MPI_Rsend` call? (I'm running the program locally, so both ranks run on my computer).

Comment: There is a big difference between "there's an error in your code" and "the program prints an error message when it runs".   It's an error to read past the end of an array, but if your C code does that, often the program will run quite happily anyway, giving results that may or may not be noticeably wrong.  One of the frustrations in this business is that wrong code sometimes works.

Comment: I think this may be a case of UB... But from the standard I agree there should be an error. Very interested to see an answer to this.

Comment: @JonathanDursi Right, I understand your example. Maybe I am misinterpreting the documentation. I found another link which states that "A ready send for which no receive exists produces an asynchronous error at the destination. The error is not detected at the MPI_Rsend and it returns MPI_SUCCESS." This is here: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_1.13.0/com.ibm.zos.r13.fomp200/ipezps00196.htm. In this case, would you interpret "produces an asynchronous error" as something that might noticeable (an error message)?

Comment: ["This document does not specify the state of a computation after an erroneous MPI call has occurred."](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node39.htm#Node39).  Falling back to a safe behaviour, generating nonsense results, crashing, or catching fire and melting into a puddle while mournfully playing the chorus of "my heart will go on" are all equally standards-compliant behaviours, although the last generally requires hardware support.

Comment: Async errors don't have a lot of API support; "Another subtle issue arises because of the nature of asynchronous communications: MPI calls may initiate operations that continue asynchronously after the call returned. Thus, the operation may return with a code indicating successful completion, yet later cause an error exception to be raised. If there is a subsequent call that relates to the same operation (e.g., a call that verifies that an asynchronous operation has completed) then the error argument associated with this call will be used to indicate the nature of the error. "

Comment: @JonathanDursi Ok. It *is* a little frustrating, this behavior. Thanks for the explanations and docs! Would you like to combine all of this in an answer that I can accept? Or should I do that?

Comment: Starting a ready-mode send before the receive operation is a semantic error with an **undefined outcome** (UO). It doesn't have to result in an error message and the standard allows for ready sends to be implemented as standard sends. And that is exactly the way Open MPI takes.

Comment: @HristoIliev "And that is exactly the way Open MPI takes" Is that **always** true for Open MPI? I mean, can I always assume that, for Open MPI, the worst case scenario of this wrong code will be a regular MPI_Send operation? If so, that's no SO bad.

Comment: No, you cannot assume anything. Currently, there is nothing in the Open MPI source code that distinguishes between ready- and standard-mode sends besides a constant, which is referenced nowhere in the backend implementation, but that could change sometime in the future. Simply do not use `MPI_Rsend` - it is an archaism, its behaviour is not well-defined, and it was made obsolete by all of the protocol optimisations in modern MPI libraries.