# MPI_Rsend:how to know that a receive buffer is already posted

Tags: mpi, openmpi, hpc

By [MPI_Rsend man papers](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Rsend.3.php),in order to use MPI_Rsend,we need to guarantee that a receive is already posted. It is an error if the receive is not posted before the ready send is called.But how to guarantee that a receive is already posted ???.I try to find some examples about MPI_Rsend,but i can not find anything.And how to get this error ? 
In this link [MPI_RSend_error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34223226/mpi-rsend-not-raising-error-when-it-should) ,finally some one said that : "*Simply do not use MPI_Rsend - it is an archaism, its behaviour is not well-defined, and it was made obsolete by all of the protocol optimisations in modern MPI libraries*".So,which MPI libraries exactly implement RSend ? In fact,using MPI_Rsend will give better performance than MPI_Send in some algorithms.
Example code:

```html
void AllGather_ring_RSend(void* data, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype,MPI_Comm communicator) 
{
  int me; 
  MPI_Comm_rank(communicator, &me); 
  int world_size; 
  MPI_Comm_size(communicator, &world_size);
  int next=me+1;
  if(next>=world_size)
      next=0;
  int prev=me-1;
  if(prev<0)
      prev=world_size-1;
  int i,curi=me;
  for(i=0;i<world_size-1;i++)
  {
     MPI_Rsend(data+curi*sizeof(int), count, datatype, next, 0, communicator);
     curi=curi-1;
     if(curi<0)
         curi=world_size-1;
     MPI_Recv(data+curi*sizeof(int), count, datatype, prev, 0, communicator, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);     
  }
}
void main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv); 
    int world_rank,world_size,namelen; 
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    int* buff=(int*) malloc(world_size*sizeof(int));
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < world_size; i++) {
          buff[i]=world_rank;
      }
      if(world_rank==0)
      for (i = 0; i < world_size; i++) 
         printf("%d\n",buff[i]);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
    AllGather_ring_RSend(buff,1,MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();   
}
```

In this code,is receive process already posted???

Answer (score 3):

MPI provides no built-in mechanism to check whether the remote rank has already posted the receive operation or not. It is up to the program's logic to ensure that it is the case by e.g. having the receiver notify somehow the sender (e.g. via a message or via the completion of a synchronisation call like `MPI_(I)Barrier`) that it has posted the receive and it is therefore safe to initiate a *ready*-mode send.

As I have already said, the ready-mode send is obsoleted by the way modern networks and MPI implementations work. Small messages are already sent asynchronously (using an eager send protocol) while the latency savings for larger messages, if any, are very much platform- & network- & implementation-dependent. **The outcome of an incorrectly used ready-mode send is not defined in the MPI standard and implementations are allowed to substitute the standard mode for the ready one.** It is therefore way too easy to get trapped into the local implementation's behaviour of the ready send and end up with an incorrect MPI code. Moreover, you cannot even write code that will reliably produce an error on all MPI implementations.

An example of an MPI library that implements ready mode as standard mode is Open MPI. MPICH implements ready mode for eager messages by checking for a matching receive upon message reception and returning an error if none found, which does not provide any performance benefit over a standard send to an already posted receive (may the MPICH guys correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Please check my code after editted.In this code,has the remote rank already posted the receive operation ???

Comment: If `MPI_Rsend` is blocking, then the receives will never get posted. If `MPI_Rsend` is buffered, then there is a race condition.

Comment: a receive is already posted which means a receive buffer is allocated with buffer size = message size . Because the receive buffer is allocated.and all process wait until all buffer is allocated,i think MPI_Rsend will send successfully

Comment: And i can not understand why "If MPI_Rsend is blocking, then the receives will never get posted. If MPI_Rsend is buffered, then there is a race condition."

Comment: To post a receive means to call `MPI_Recv` or `MPI_Irecv` or `MPI_Recv_init` followed by `MPI_Start`. Allocating a buffer is not enough on its own. As to the second question, I think it's obvious that all ranks are first calling `MPI_Rsend` and only after that `MPI_Recv`. Whether this will result in an error (if any) or not depends on how much time it takes the messages traverse the network vs how much time it takes the CPU to execute the code from `MPI_Rsend` to the middle of `MPI_Recv`.